# `Exception has occurred: OSError` when the file is there

Tags: python, file, oserror

When running `import ssdeep` ([source](https://github.com/MacDue/ssdeep-windows-32_64)), I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ssdeep_windows_32_64-0.0.1-py3.10.egg/ssdeep/bin\fuzzy_64.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  File "/home/WE1S/preprocessing/libs/fuzzyhasher/fuzzyhasher.py", line 19, in <module>
    import ssdeep
  File "/home/20230614_1549_test/modules/import/scripts/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libs.fuzzyhasher.fuzzyhasher import FuzzyHasher
OSError: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ssdeep_windows_32_64-0.0.1-py3.10.egg/ssdeep/bin\fuzzy_64.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, the file is there:

```
ls '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ssdeep_windows_32_64-0.0.1-py3.10.egg/ssdeep/bin'
fuzzy.dll  fuzzy_64.dll
```

Why is that? I'm on [WSL 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm on WSL2.

If you're on WSL, you're on a Linux system. A package for Windows won't cut it there.

Try installing the regular `ssdeep` with `pip install ssdeep` inside your WSL environment instead.

Comment: well, [that gives error either](https://github.com/DinoTools/python-ssdeep/issues/66#issuecomment-1596053804). However, even if it's a wrong package to use, at least it should be another error, not "file not found" like this?

Comment: That's a different error – it means you're missing the tools required to build Python extensions. (Try `apt install python3-dev build-essential` to begin with.) And anyway, if you look closely, the slashes in `ssdeep/bin\fuzzy_64.dll` have the OS looking for a file called `bin\fuzzy_64.dll` in the `ssdeep` directory.